# Find parentheses in regular expression

Tags: java, android, regex, parentheses

I wrote this pattern:

```
final String FRACTION_PATTERN = "^([n0-9\\-\\+\\(\\)]+)/([0-9]+)$";
```

In order to match expressions like: n+2/6 or (n-3)/4

When I am using parentheses, there is no match.
What am I doing wrong?

Note that I used square brackets for the regular expression and the order of characters inside does not matter.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you use `([n0-9+()-]` as first group?

Comment: [Your regex matches the examples](https://regex101.com/r/uH5kW3/1). Please provide strings that your regex must handle.

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. You can't parse general arithmetic expressions with regular expression technology. You need a parser.

Comment: If you want to support expressions with parenthesis, then you also want to support nested parenthesis, e.g. `((5+7)*4-7)/(3+2)`, and regex cannot handle that. So follow the advise by @EJP and use an expression parser, not a regex matcher.

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote this pattern:
>
> `final String FRACTION_PATTERN = "^([n0-9\\-\\+\\(\\)]+)/([0-9]+)$";`
>
> In order to match expressions like: n+2/6 or (n-3)/4

**Stop right there!**

You're using the wrong tool for the job. You can't analyze general arithmetic expressions with a regular expression technology.

This was proven in the 1950s. You need a parser. Have a look for Dijkstra's [**Shunting-yard algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), or [**recursive descent expression parser**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Comment: I do not think it is an answer. If you want to suggest using some other library, you should do that in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Put the minus sign in front so it does not have the meaning of a range

```
^([-n0-9\\-\\+\\(\\)]+)/([0-9]+)$
```

Note the 4th character of the regex

There is also some redundancy in the character class. This is a simplification:

```
^([-n0-9+\\()]+)/([0-9]+)$
```

Comment: It does not have a meaning of a range in OP regex.

Comment: Your regexps are the same as OP's, just with less escaping.

Comment: @stribizhev When you put the dash - as the first character in the class it will match a dash and loose its meaning for specifying a range. The OP wants to match the dash literally looking at his second example.

Comment: `\\-` is an escaped hyphen, it already does not create a range.

Comment: @stribizhev Well no, it does create a range. The range with a backslash and a backslash.. \\-\\

Comment: @stribizhev That's because it does create a range. Hope you see it with this demo https://regex101.com/r/qT8sI4/1 It does not match a hyphen see? It matches a backslash cause it falls in the range between backslash and backslash

Comment: In Java, ``\\`` is used to write a single ``\``. Your regex101 demo should be actually written as [`[\-\]`](https://regex101.com/r/qT8sI4/2). OP regex at regex101 should look like [`^([n0-9\-\+\(\)]+)\/([0-9]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/bN1nV7/1).

Comment: I understand what you mean now, the extra escaping for java. My answer is just the regex and not a regex in a given language. In C# we can have verbatim string written as @"literal" which doesn't introduce extra escaping concerns except for the double quote. There is no need for escaping the characters inside a char class as they loose their special meaning. Except for the - which required escaping unless you place it as the first character : [-n0-9+()] or a bit shorter [-n\d+()]

Comment: I know C# and verbatim string literals. This is a Java question, and you answer does not answer the question.

Comment: I'm sure it is also a regex question. I'm not fluent in Java